# Calculate number of months from number of days

Tags: php

It is a quite simple question, but I am not being able to find a solution for it. I have been digging around internet for quite few days now to find a proper solution. I know that the solution must be simple, but its just I cannot figure it out in my mind.

```
        $datetimeToday = new DateTime(date('d M Y'));
        $datetimeAccountExpirationDate= new DateTime($account->expiration_date);
        $interval = $datetimeToday->diff($datetimeAccountExpirationDate);
        $days = $interval->format('%R%a');
        $days = intval($days);

        if($days <= 0):
            // calculate the number of months, a month is of 30 days (for this app)
        endif;
```

I am calculating the date difference from today and the day the account is getting expired. I get a `+` value if the account is yet to expire and a `-` value if the account is expired. I am then converting it to `integet` and then if its less than `0` , I need to calculate the number of months so that I can calculate the costs for my clients accordingly. A month is of exact `30 days` in the application that I am developing.

It should give the value as follows

```
    if $days = 20 then $months = 1 // from 1 - 30, it should give 1
    if $days = 35 then $months = 2 // from 31 - 60, it should give 2
```

and so on.

EDIT :

```
var_dump($datetimeToday->diff($datetimeAccountExpirationDate)->d); // this would give me days
var_dump($datetimeToday->diff($datetimeAccountExpirationDate)->m); // this would return 0 for days > 0 but < 30
```

Comment: I'd suggest familiarizing yourself with `strtotime();` and `date()`

Comment: You just have to use a simple modulo if you don't care about months being either 30 or 31 days and February being special...

Answer (score 0):

It is as easy as running something like this.

```
$date = "April";
$days_in_month = date("t", strtotime($date));
```

The `$date` is a string representation of the month you want. and `strtotime` will convert it to a timestamp (in this example; 1460073600).  Then you can use `date` and using the `t` setting, it will return the days in the month given.  This example will give you `30` in the variable `$days_in_month`

For the `$date` you can use any representation of a date.  For example, `Feb 2016` as the date will give you `29` days... but `Feb 2015` will give you `28` days